# How do I have the previous and next buttons below show the next and previous images in a loop

Tags: jquery, loops, button

How would I go about having the previous and next buttons below show the next and previous featured image and pertaining thumb image in a loop?

The following is in a loop:

```
 <?php 
$array = array(
    $productNumber = 1,
    $btnPrevNumber = 1,
    $btnNxtNumber = 1,
    $thumbNumber = 1); ?>


    <div class="pre pre<?php echo $nxtNumber++; ?>">
      <h2>previous</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="next next<?php echo $nxtNumber++; ?>">
      <h2>next</h2>
    </div>

   <!--featured images-->
    <div class="collection-img collection-img<?php echo $productNumber++; ?>"></div>

   <!--thumbs images-->
    <div class="col-thumb col-thumb<?php echo $thumbNumber++; ?>">
    </div>
```

This is the jquery

```
for(let y = 1; y <= 50; y++){
$(".col-thumb"+y).click(function(){
$(".collection-img").fadeOut(); 
$(".collection-img"+y).fadeIn("slow");
 });
}
```

Comment: You need to show more of your HTML. It's highly likely that you don't even need more than one set of `pre` and `next` buttons.

Comment: And a general tip: If you find yourself numbering things like variable names, **you are already doing it wrong**. This is always true, independent of programming language used. You don't need CSS classes `thing1` through `thing50`, that defies the entire purpose of CSS. It is even detrimental, because this kind of thing makes you start copy-pasting code, exactly as you did here. There is always a better way to solve a task than to use "numbered"/"counted" variables, so stop and think early the next time you notice this pattern.

Comment: Since the question now looks completely different, guess my answer isn't relevant anymore